# Storing variables with sessions django

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

This is my code:

views.py:

```
def some_function(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('template.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form})) 
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        input_word = request.POST['input_word']

        if 'word_choice' in request.POST:
            word_choice = request.POST['word_choice']
        else:
            word_choice = ''

        var1 = HelperClass(input_word).func1()
        table1 = HelperClass(input_word).table_one()
        table2 = HelperClass(input_word).table_two()
        word_selected = word_choice

        content = {
            'form': form,
            'input_word': input_word,
            'var1': var1,
            'table1' : table1,
            'table2' : table2,
            'word_selected': word_selected,
        }

        return render_to_response('result_template.html', RequestContext(request, content))
    else:
        raise Http404
```

This is result_template.html:

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="/admin/find-word/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="input_word" type="text" name="input_word" maxlength="100"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <form />

    <h1>{% trans "You entered" %} "{{ input_word }}" </h1>
    <p>{{ var1 }}</p>

    <form action="/admin/find-root/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <h3>{% trans "Table2" %}</h3>
        {% for word in table2 %}
            # Get info from database and display it on the current template.
            <input type="radio" name='word_choice' value="{{ word }}"> {{ word }}<br>
        {% endfor %}

        <h3>{% trans "Table3" %}</h3>
        {% for word in table3 %}
           {# Get info from database and display it on the current template. #}
            <input type="radio" name='word_choice' value="{{ word }}"> {{ word }}<br>
        {% endfor %}

        <p>{% trans "You selected: " %}{{ word_selected }}</p>

        {# Submit the word of choice.#}
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    <form />
{% endblock %}
```

I need to add code to views.py, so that:

---

1. it shows result, that was rendered after submitting the first form
   (when assining input_word)
2. new result shows, when resubmitting the first form
3. when submitting second form redirect to success_template.html (this part I can do myself)

I know, that I need to use sessions here. I've tried different things, but I'm lost now.

Comment: You don't *need* sessions - you could as well pass state from one request to another using hidden fields in your forms. With your state being local to a single view, that's easier and more predictable than using a session. Also and as a side note: you shouldn't be using a POST here, your view only retrieve informations so it's really a GET.

Comment: I edited the code in views.py as actually I have it written.
tamplate.html has only the first form (input field and submit button)
Does your comment still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Create a session variable in django as follows.

```
request.session['key'] = value
```

Access it by

```
request.session['key']     # or
request.session.get('key')
```

remove it by

```
del request.session['key']
```

Answer (score 0):

In django you can simply assign values to sessions with:

```
request.session['value']
```

In your case you'd have to replace the `word_selected` variable with `request.session['word_selected']`